# How to enable paragraph tools on NSTextView rich text view (.rtf)

Tags: swift, toolbar, rtf, nstextview, macos-big-sur

I updated to macOS Big Sur and my NSTextView inspector bar no longer has the paragraph tools I need.  In macOS Catalina the NSTextView with Rich Text enabled had paragraph tools within the inspector bar.  I cannot figure out how to get them back in Big Sur

NSTextView Inspector bar in Catalina
[image]

NSTextView Inspector bar in Big Sur
[image: NSTextView Inspector bar in Big Sur]

How do I get these paragraph tools back?